# Make an http request on document load using cyclejs

Tags: cyclejs

How do I make an http request to a webservice on document load using cyclejs?
The examples cover reacting to user input and don't meet my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to create a request stream and pass it to the HTTPDriver.
For example:

```
const request$ = Rx.Observable.just({
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    method: 'GET'
});
```

Then:

```
return {
  HTTP: request$
};
```